# Best way to start JBoss AS

Tags: jboss6.x

I like to ask what is best way to start jboss AS.

Because, whenever i close terminal or press ctrl+c then jboss, which is already started with `run.sh` script, start with shutdown. I have already tried executing `export LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1` before starting jboss via script `.run.sh` but it has not helped me much.

Secondly, i like to know how can i validate that jboss is running except browsing `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8080/admin-console`.

I am using both mac-osx/linux and  Jboss-AS-6.0.0.Final.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nohup /usr/local/jboss/bin/run.sh -b 0.0.0.0  > /dev/null &` should do starting jb as well running it in background.

You can check for jboss running using `ps -ef | grep java`

Comment: Where to check for logs when server is started using this command?

Comment: Ok. the logs location is not getting affected. It is still in jboss logs folder.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of the question, try running:

`./run.sh &`

This will send the process to the background.  Just hit enter once JBoss has finished starting up.

If you need to bring the process back to the foreground, run `fg`.  You can then hit CTRL-C if you want stop JBoss.

To validate that jboss is running, you can run something like this :

`ps -ef | grep jboss`

or

`ps -ef | grep run.sh`

This will show the process id for JBoss or the run.sh script.

I hope this helps.